# Deploying Angular 10 app with loopback on google app engine

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, loopback

I am new to Angular and build my Angular 10 app with Loopback as backend to deal with all crud functions with my MySQL database. My Angular app is working on localhost:4200 and Loopback on localhost:3000. Now I want to deploy my app on google app engine standard environment. I am able to deploy angular app and angular is working fine. But how to connect loopback on google app engine.

I run this commands to build my app inside root folder

```
    ng build --prod
```

This created dist folder and I have deployed it with app.yml file.
Content of app.yml file

```
    runtime: python37
    manual_scaling:
        instances: 5
    service: angular

    handlers:
        - url: /
          static_files: my-app/index.html
          upload: my-app/index.html
        - url: /
          static_dir: my-app
```

Comment: you will just have to host your backend too, if its a nodejs backend maybe this can help https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/quickstart

Comment: could you share more details about your backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to deploy Nodejs Backend as a different service on GAE and call your angular loopback on that service URL, deploy nodejs with below app.yaml config

```
#app.yaml
 runtime: nodejs
 manual_scaling:
   instances: 5
 service: angular
 env: flex
```

gcloud app deploy

This will create URL something like this

> https://angular-dot-{project-id}.{region}.appspot.com

then in your app look for "app.component.ts" file generally inside src/app/
and change below configuration

```
LoopBackConfig.setBaseURL('https://angular-dot-{project-id}.{region}.appspot.com');
```

Then create a production configuration of your angular app by :

```
ng build --prod
```

it will create a **dist** directory,
create an app.yaml file for deploying it on the cloud as shown below

Angular Application App.yaml

```
#app.yaml
runtime: python37
manual_scaling:
    instances: 5
service: ang-loop
handlers:
    - url: /
      static_files: my-app/index.html
      upload: my-app/index.html
    - url: /
      static_dir: my-app
```

move app.yaml file inside dist directory.

then deploy it on google cloud using (inside **dist** directory)

```
gcloud app deploy
```

This should work!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy your backend code on another app engine service and you have to use that service URL as an API URL in your angular app.

For example: backend is deployed on API service and its' URL is something like https://api-dot-{project-id}.{region}.appspot.com then use this URL as an API url.

App.yaml file should be look like:

```
runtime: python37
service: api

runtime_config:
  document_root: public // web accessible path here
  whitelist_functions: shell_exec

env_variables:
```